# viewController automatically plays for set time then switches to next viewContrllofer

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, nstimer

hi I want the viewController to appear for a set time then dissolve to a new viewController.
Possibly using nstimer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(toNewViewController:) withObject:nil afterDelay:timeInSeconds];
```

That is. You only have to write the view controller to view controller transition in the method toNewViewController: .